# Stanford's StanfordCPPLib on linux

Tags: c++, linux

I'm using Suse Linux 13.1 and self studding Stanford's CS 106b course. Here I have found ziped libraries http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/homework/2-ngrams/cs106b-hw2-ngrams-starter-files.zip and downloaded.
Now questions:

1. This libs are for windows, so some changes will be needed to make them work correctly in linux. what changes?
2. Where to put this folder, so that gcc compiler could automatically find this libs?

Comment: I can't find the mentioned zips. Maybe a direct link?

Comment: Sorry, here it is: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/homework/2-ngrams/cs106b-hw2-ngrams-starter-files.zip

Comment: You should edit your question and put that link in it

Comment: Look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/progabstrlib/files/latest/download?source=files , in particular the readme in the download.

Answer (score 1):

This quarter, the CS106B and CS106X course websites is behind WebAuth (Stanford's authentication system), so you won't be able to access the site directly. Usually, though, the site is open to everyone and you can go and download any of the assignments. We've recently added support for Linux by unifying all the starter libraries into one and providing Qt Creator starter files. If you wait until the summer, the instructors for that quarter might make all the materials available online again and you should have no trouble getting the most recent version of the starter files.

Hope this helps!